# how to return a number from UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I have a function like

I want `getResponse` to return the index of the button pressed.

```
-(NSNumber*)getResponse
        {
        ...
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                    message:@"Message"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Si",nil];
        [alert show];
        return """Index of button Pressed"""
    }
```

`getResponse` looks `prefUser` data in order to return a number 0 or 1 but there are some combinations that are to be asked to the user in order to know what to return.

User may check allways save data (so it returns 1)
Or may check never save data (...returns 0)
Ask me every time:
It's like:

> ¿do you want to save the data? (YES/NO)

Comment: Do you know about delegation??? How to implement it?? Go through it http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-uialertview-and-uialertviewdelegate--mobile-3159

Comment: How does your `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` look like?

Comment: You should know that UIAlertView is deprecated starting with iOS 8. You should use UIAlertController instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate method, first set up view controller as UIAlertViewDelegate:

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

and add that delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // button index it what you are looking for
}
```